# In Scalzi's "The Last Colony", how did the CDF know that Perry offered Gau a chance to surrender?

Tags: old-mans-war, john-scalzi, the-last-colony

In John Scalzi's "The Last Colony", John Perry talks with General Gau when General Gau comes to destroy his colony. Perry instead gives him a chance to surrender which General Gau doesn't take and the conclave's fleet is destroyed. Perry is then called in for a hearing in front of a panel to explain this possible treasonous act. My question is, how did the CDF know what their conversation was about? How did they know what exactly they talked about and that Perry offered Gau a chance to retreat? There is no indication that there was someone nearby recording video/audio. Was Perry wearing a bug/camera or something? Is such surveillance (in that universe) possible from space?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remember that the his primary role in the plan was to talk to Gau and give him a message.  The CDF would want a recorded verification that the message was correctly delivered.

Also, recall that Gau claimed that all such evacuations were heavily documented and published to pretty much everyone.  At least some of them were recorded because the colonists were given the recordings (with deceptive edits) from the CDF.

It would be very surprising to me if he wasn't being recorded by all parties involved.

Comment: Cool, I just imagined that Perry wouldn't deliberately get himself into trouble. I thought he was being monitored without his knowledge/consent. But makes sense. After all he did think highly of Gau and was no doubt himself being honorable to an honorable adversary.

Comment: Also remember that Perry himself warns Gau that he shouldn't be telling him what he did (that he has one chance to leave), which implies he was being listening to.